# Passing external data to std::set Compare functor

Tags: c++

This is a contrived example, I know it doesn't make sense in this context. In my real case, `v` contains a larger class, and I can't refactor `v` due to other dependencies in the code base. Also, in the real case I'm not using `std::set` but it simplifies the example. Here are two example classes `A` and `B` that I know don't work, and I do understand why, but hopefully will illustrate what I'm trying to do:

```
#include <set>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct A
{
    A(initializer_list<float> init) : v(init)
    {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < init.size(); ++i)
        {
            s.insert(i);
        }
    }

    struct Less
    {
        Less(const vector<float>& v) : v(v) {};

        bool operator()(size_t i, size_t j)
        {
            return v[i] < v[j];
        }

        const vector<float>& v;
    };

    vector<float> v;
    set<size_t, Less> s;
};

struct B
{
    B(initializer_list<float> init) : v(init)
    {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < init.size(); ++i)
        {
            s.insert(i);
        }
    }

    template<const vector<float>& v>
    struct Less
    {
        bool operator()(size_t i, size_t j)
        {
            return v[i] < v[j];
        }
    };

    vector<float> v;
    set<size_t, Less<v>> s;
};

int main()
{
    A a = {1., 2., 3.};
    B b = {1., 2., 3.};
}
```

In both cases `s` contains indicies that refer to elements in `v`, and `Less` is trying to compare the values in `v` using those indices. Is there a way to do this that I'm not seeing?

Comment: I'm using `unordered_map` so maybe your idea will still work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `A` approach is almost correct. It just needs 2 fixes:

- `bool operator()(size_t i, size_t j)` should be `const`.
- `s` must have a configured functor passed to it during construction.

```
struct A
{
    A(initializer_list<float> init) : v(init), s(v)
    {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < init.size(); ++i)
        {
            s.insert(i);
        }
    }

    // These must be manually defined if you need them, the default
    // ones won't be correct.
    A(const A&) = delete; 
    A& operator=(const A&) = delete;

    struct MyLess
    {
        MyLess(const vector<float>& v) : v(v) {};

        bool operator()(size_t i, size_t j) const
        {
            return v[i] < v[j];
        }

        const vector<float>& v;
    };

    vector<float> v;
    set<size_t, MyLess> s;
};
```

> I'm using unordered_map so maybe your idea will still work?

Yes, the same principle applies to `std::unordered_set`. You just have to pass in both `hash` and `key_equal` during construction.  Check out the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/unordered_set) to identify the correct constructor to invoke.

Comment: A word of caution, this solution needs to implement [the Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) because it has a member that self-references the class. For example if you use the default copy constructor, then the copy's `s`'s comparator won't refer the correct `v`.

Comment: To clarify the caveat mentionned by @FrançoisAndrieux, they are talking about making sure the rule of 3/5/0 is implemented on `struct A` itself.